# Генерация exe файла

Tags: python, exe, brainfuck, компилятор

Подскажите по каком принципу генерируется *.exe файлы.
Сейчас есть задача написать аналог brainfuck (академ. интерес). Интерпретатор написан, в интернете 99% текст о лексическом анализе , лишь генерация exe для меня проблема.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для формирования экзешника нужно знать формат Portable Executable, плюс знать как генерировать машинный код. Намного проще будет генерировать промежуточный ассемблерный исходник (или исходник на чистом Си, как переносимом эквиваленте ассемблера), а потом уже его компилировать в exe.

Comment: В прочем, TrueЪ кодер сможет написать исполняемый файл побайтно в блокноте .

Comment: Ассемблер по сути это машинный код, записанный с помощью человекочитаемых мнемоник. Большой разницы между генерацией ассемблера и машинного кода нет. Вы вероятно имели в виду, что часто удобно высокоуровневый язык (такой как Java) перегнать в промежуточный язык (такой как Java bytecode, [LLVM IR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLVM#Intermediate_representation)) и его позже интерпретировать/в машинный код превращать на лету (JIT)/создавать исполняемый файл под конкретную машину.  @0xFFh: настоящему программисту нужна только [намагниченная иголка и твёрдая рука](https://xkcd.com/378/)

Comment: @jfs, я сталкивался с программной генерацией машинного кода, и могу сказать, что ассемблер и машинный код - по сложности генерации это очень разные вещи. Если можно использовать промежуточный слой абстракции в виде ассемблера - то лучше использовать его. Вопрос был о генерации PE файла, ответ был о том же - лучше воспользоваться инструментами, которые уже умеют генерировать PE или объектные файлы.

Comment: @insolor мне приходилось и ассемблер и компилятор и интерпретатор реализовывать. Я вам и не предлагал linker писать. Совершенно согласен, что лучше под конкретную машину код уже существующими инструментами генерить, поэтому я уже и упомянул промежуточные форматы такие как Java bytecode, LLVM IR. Если уж вы хотите использовать ассемблер в качестве промежуточного формата, то лучше С использовать (как "переносимый ассемблер").

Comment: @jfs, если бы изначально писал ответ сейчас, а не пять лет назад, то наверное предложил бы Си. Добавил в ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Вот вам [Анализ приложения защищенного виртуальной машиной](http://habrahabr.ru/post/218887/). Это то что Вы хотите сделать! Автор этого кейгенми встроил вирт.машину, которая является интерпретатором Брайнфака. Но на мой взгляд этот брайнфак не особо интересен. Рекомендую Вам другую Вычислительную машину: [Копирование Бита – Простейшая Вычислительная Машина](http://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/bbjr/bbjr.utf8) она более интересная ;)

Но как понимаю Вы хотите сделать нечто не понятное, тогда спуститесь на самый низкий уровень! Все электронные вычислительные устройства работающие с 1 и 0, т.е. в двоичной системе счисления состоят либо из И-НЕ или ИЛИ-НЕ. Ранее, при СССР была популярной микросхема К155ЛА3 и ее вариации К555ЛА3, К1533ЛА3, которая содержала 4 элемента 2И-НЕ, т.е. входа элемента и один выход элемента Шеффера. Вот на ней чего только не делали, диву даешься. Я к тому, что если и имеет смысл ковыряться с эзотерикой(эзотерические языки), то с пользой для себя. В академическом плане лучше спуститься до базовых элементах, еще лучше поймете как работают компы!

Answer (score 1):

У меня была практически такая же задача. И решил ее очень просто - не генерировал готовый exe, а asm файл для [fasm](http://flatassembler.net/). Так как asm файл - это обычный текстовый файл, то проблем с генерацией не будет.

Само решение будет состоять с двух частей. Первая часть - это преобразование каждой команды в ассемблерные эквиваленты (это не очень сложно). Вторая часть - это такой себе runtime. Нужно просто выделить массив и инициализировать некие переменные. Эта часть будет постоянной.

Answer (score 1):

В качестве backend-компилятора для i386 используйте [Tiny C Compiler](http://www.bellard.org/tcc/) (с) Fabrice Bellard

TCC умеет компилировать не только в .exe/.dll/.so, но и в память (а-ля JIT).
Подаете ему на вход исходник на Си в строке, опционально внешние функции, которые могут быть вызваны из скомпилированного исходника (только в режиме JIT), дергаете компилятор, получаете .exe или указатель на скомпилированную функцию.

Вообще лучше гененировать не .exe а **объектный файл** в формате .elf если пользуетесь MinGW, или coff для VisualC

PS: посмотрев теги вопроса: а почему собственно не [использовать PyPy](https://habrahabr.ru/post/124418/) ? Минус разве что недоступна генерация standalone кода (только JIT).

Answer (score 0):

Мало того, что вам придётся писать генератор ассемблерного кода, вполне возможно вам ещё придётся в форме ресурса интегрировать в вашу программу (вполне возможно -- не как отдельный файл) и сам ассемблер. Каким-то образом его сохранять во временную папку, после чего, запускать его там на компиляцию, и ко всему прочему -- каким-то образом ошибки компиляции возвращать на уровень вашего эзотерического языка программирования. ) совсем не тривиальная задача. )