# Машинный код и компиляция в него — это как?

Tags: компиляция, компилятор, машинный-код

- Как работает компиляция в машинный код и как это устроено?
- Как сделать программу на машинном коде самостоятельно?
- Например, как написать такой компилятор на JS, Python, C или C++?

Хочу поработать с этим, потому что всегда мечтал попробовать собрать `.exe` самостоятельно, без помощи готовых компиляторов.

Comment: Если идти от сложного: изучить [мануалы intel по платформе x86](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm) - чтобы знать как писать машинный код, перед этим еще изучить ассемблер, хотя бы на минимальном уровне; изучить формат исполняемых файлов для вашей системы (portable executable для Windows или ELF для Linux); изучить как вообще создаются компиляторы - тут ["Книга Дракона"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Компиляторы:_принципы,_технологии_и_инструменты) в помощь.

Comment: Если от более простого - отказаться от идеи самому создавать бинарник, а генерировать например промежуточный Си код, который уже будет компилироваться в бинарный (или воспользоваться инструментарием [LLVM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLVM)). Но опять же в этом случае все равно нужно будет изучить "Книгу Дракона".

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Генерация exe файла](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/108831)

Comment: Не совсем по теме, но, возможно, вдохновит - [история одного байта](https://habr.com/ru/post/27055/), [fermi paradox](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JZ6ZzJeWgpY)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Baremetal

Каждый конкретный процессор (например, Intel Core i3-4160 или ARM Cortex-A9) имеет свою *микроархитектуру* и реализует *архитектуру уровня набора команд* (англ. *instruction set architecture*).

- [**Микроархитектура**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0) определяет структуру процессора на уровне электронных компонентов и логических вентилей.
- [**Архитектура уровня набора команд (ISA)**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4), грубо говоря, определяет то, какие команды может выполнять процессор. Эта архитектура абстрагированна от микроархитектуры. Процессоры разных комнаний могут реализовывать одну и ту же архитектуру (например, многие процессоры Intel и AMD реализует одно и то же семейство архитектур [x86](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86)).

Если два процессора реализуют одну и ту же ISA, то они могут исполнять одни и те же программы. ISA определяет, какие команды доступны программисту, какие регистры он может использовать, как он может использовать страничную адресацию, виртуальную память и т. д. Кроме того, она определяет **формат команд**, которые понимает процессор.

Каждая программа процессора — это просто набор подряд идущих команд. При своем запуске процессор выбирает команду из память по адресу, называемому *вектором сброса* (англ. [*reset vector*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reset_vector)) и начинает исполнять эту программу, пока питание не будет отключено.

Написать программу в машинных кодах достаточно просто — нужно лишь взять справочник по ISA (например, [Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer Manuals](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm)), которую реализует ваш процессор и написать нужные команды байт за байтом.

Конечно, в наше время никто в машинных кодах не пишет, потому что человеку тяжело работать с большим объемом чисел и сложными форматами команд (особенно в x86). Из-за таких сложностей были придуманы [*языки ассемблера*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AF%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA_%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0), которые вводят простые мнемоники для инструкций процессора.

Например, одна инструкция ассемблера x86 `MOV` может кодировать около 20 различных инструкций процессора `MOV`<sup>1</sup>. Ассемблер читает вашу программу на языке ассемблера и переводит ее в бинарный файл<sup>2</sup>, который, опять же, является просто последовательность байт, кодирующих подряд идущие инструкции процессора.

Вот так может выглядет отрывок программы на языке ассемблера:

```
cli
lgdt (gdtr)
mov %cr0, %eax
or $0x1, %eax
mov %eax, %cr0
```

Вот так выглядит программа на машинном языке:

```
0000000 05ea 007c 3100 8ec0 8ed8 bcd0 7c00 1688
0000010 7cdb c031 c08e 00bb 8a80 db16 b67c b100
0000020 b502 b000 e830 0053 59e8 8400 75c0 fa30
0000030 010f f416 0f7c c020 8366 01c8 220f eac0
0000040 7c44 0008 b866 0010 d88e c08e e08e e88e
0000050 d08e 00bc 07c0 e800 03a4 0000 ebf4 befd
0000060 7cbc 03e8 f400 fdeb 5350 30fc b4ff ac0e
0000070 c084 0474 10cd f7eb 585b b4c3 cd02 7213
0000080 3102 c3c0 1e9c 0657 fa56 c031 d88e 10bf
0000090 f705 8ed0 bec0 0500 058a 2650 048a 2650
00000a0 04c6 c600 be05 8026 be3c 2658 0488 8858
00000b0 3105 74c0 4001 075e 1f5f c39d 3241 2030
00000c0 7369 6420 7369 6261 656c 2e64 4820 6c61
00000d0 2074 6874 2065 5043 2e55 0000 0000 0000
00000e0 0000 0000 ffff 0000 9a00 00cf ffff 0000
00000f0 9200 00cf 0017 7cdc 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

Очевидно, что асссемблерный код и читать, и писать проще.

Теперь у вас достаточно знаний, чтобы открыть справочник, как по словарю, написать программу в машинных кодах и исполнить ее на процессоре. Но, это не сработает в случае, если вы хотите написать программу, которая будет работать в какой-либо операционной системе.

#### Операционная система

Операционная система — это еще один уровень абстрации, который полностью лишает нас возможности неограниченно пользоваться нашим процессором, заставляя его исполнять любые наши команды<sup>3</sup>. ОС делает очень много различных вещей, но остановимся только на одной — запуск исполняемых файлов.

Как я уже сказал, каждая программа *процессора* — это просто последовательность команд, однако каждая программа *операционной системы* — это особая последовательность байт, имеющая специальную структуру, в которую входят не только команды процессора.

Если брать в пример ОС Windows 10, она работает с исполняемыми файлами `.exe`, которые имеют специальный формат, называемый [Portable Executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable). Он имеет довольно сложную [структуру](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1b/Portable_Executable_32_bit_Structure_in_SVG_fixed.svg). Помимо собственно набора машинных команд он содержит в себе информацию необходимую для определения адреса и размера секций, таблиц импорта и экспорта, специальную сигнатуру и т. д.

Поэтому чтобы вручную написать программу в машинных кодах, которая будет запускаться в Windows 10, например, нам, по-мимо написания самой программы, потребуется привести ее к формату Portable Executable.

Но и этого будет не достаточно. Нам придется ознакомится с соглашениями, которые называются [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) и написать программу в машинных кодах, используя именно эти соглашения, а не какие-то другие.

Здесь необходимо, чтобы все части паззла подходили друг к другу по форме: программа должна быть валидной для процессора, формат бинарного файла должен быть понятен операционной системе, программа должна уметь корректно общаться с ОС и т. д. Это все очень сложно обеспечить, если писать программу в шестнадцатеричном редакторе.

Можете начать с написания программ на языке ассемблера (да, вам придется еще выучить синтаксис конкретного языка ассемблера и [диалект](https://imada.sdu.dk/~kslarsen/dm546/Material/IntelnATT.htm) Intel или AT&T). «Hello, World» на языке [NASM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netwide_Assembler) будет выглядеть [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1023600/8086115):

> ```
> ; ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ; helloworld.asm
> ;
> ; This is a Win32 console program that writes "Hello, World" on one line and
> ; then exits.  It needs to be linked with a C library.
> ; ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
>     global  _main
>     extern  _printf
>
>     section .text
> _main:
>     push    message
>     call    _printf
>     add     esp, 4
>     ret
> message:
>     db  'Hello, World', 10, 0
> ```

#### А нужно ли вам это?

В наше время компьютеры стали очень сложными, с десятками слоями абстраций. Даже инструкции ISA современных процессоров — не атомарные сущности, и процессоры выполняет каждую такую инструкцию как набор еще более мелких инструкций — *микрооперации* (из таких мокроопераций складывается [*микрокод*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4)).

На самом деле, умение писать на языке ассемблера (а тем более, на машинном языке) довольно бесполезно. Умение просто читать и понимать ассемблерный листинг гораздо более практично и действительно может вам пригодится.

А непрактично это в первую очередь потому, что ничего сложнее «Hello, World!» в машинных кодах вы не напишете. На ассемблере — да, напишете, но потратите на это колоссальное количество времени, которое можно было бы потратить на более полезные вещи.

---

<sup>1. Что интересно, инструкция `MOV` в x86 является [Тьюринг-полной](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%A2%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D1%83), т. е. любая программа может быть написана с использованием одной только этой инструкции. Есть даже специальный [компилятор](https://github.com/xoreaxeaxeax/movfuscator), который использует только одну эту инструкцию.</sup>

<sup>2. Некоторые ассемблеры могут сразу формировать исполняемые файлы  в нужном формате. В том числе и Portable Executable.</sup>

<sup>3. Я говорю о современных ОС типа Windows или Linux.</sup>